# Inserting data into table puts lock on clustered index of table referenced by foreign key

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, deadlock, database-deadlocks

We have a legacy database that suffers from deadlocks but we cannot do drastic code changes at the moment because the SQL is embedded in the C# app.

One deadlock occurs when inserting data into a table; it puts a lock on the clustered index of the table referenced by a foreign key.

Is there any way to insert data but force the inserted foreign key to not go and look at the indexes of referenced table?

Insert statement below:

```
INSERT INTO STKTAKEDETAILS (STK_TAKE_ID, LINE_NO, FIXTURE_NO, SKU_ID)
    SELECT STKTAKEID, LINE_NO, FIXTURE_NO, SKU_ID 
    FROM #STKTKBATCH
```

where `SKU_ID` is the foreign key.

Comment: You need that lock to ensure that the value being inserted is valid. It prevents changes to the referenced table for the duration of the insert. I suppose you could disable the foreign key for the insert but that kind of defeats the point of the foreign key. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Yes. I am being pushed towards solutions that aren't great. I was hoping to find a way of query hinting to not default to using the foreign table clustered index.

Comment: You can't query hint your way out of referential integrity (well maybe with nolock). This is actually a good thing.

Comment: @SeanLange I'd be happy with the referential integrity, if only it didn't read from the clustered index. Ideally, there'd be a second unique index I could force it to use.

Comment: By definition is MUST read your primary key (also the clustered index it seems in this case) of the table being referenced. That is the point of a foreign key. When the insert happens it must ensure that the value exists in the referenced table.